# How to select li element using Selenium in Python

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, python, menu

[image]

I am trying to automate something on shopify, and depending on what the variable (lets say x) is, I want it to go into that list.

For example, if x=2, then from that ul/li(list), how can I make it click the 2nd option (Standard 3pcs)?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to click the <li> element? Or the check-box within? If you only click on the <li> it may not necessarily click/select the check-box. So if possible share your HTML with the check-box element so that people can help you in the right way.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer!

You can use "/li[1]" at the end for picking the first item on the list.
If you want the second item, then it would be "/li[2]" and so forth.

My example:

```
search = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@class='Polaris-ResourceList_r589e']/li[" + str(variant[x]) + "]").click()
```

In this example, I am using a variable for the #, but if it's static for you, and you only need to get the 2nd item on the list, then it would be this:

```
search = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@class='Polaris-ResourceList_r589e']/li[2]").click()
```