# Python & Selenium: Finding and activating a dropdown list, then selecting a list item

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

I'm writing a Python program (with Selenium) to automatically download data from a website and then log out, but cannot figure out how to get to the logout menu item, which is in a drop-down list.  I'm a NOOB at this, so please bear with me.

I've reviewed a number of posts here to see if I could sort it out (including [this one](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/49665/how-to-select-li-element-using-selenium-in-python)), to no avail.

Here is the HTML code; the item that renders the dropdown list is highlighted. No matter what I try, Selenium either cannot find the item I need to click or it finds the item and says it's not clickable.  How do I get the dropdown menu to appear so I can click on the "Logout" list item?

[image]

Once I get the dropdown menu to appear, I need to select the item with an ID of "logout" in the HTML code below.  What is the proper way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After playing around a bit, I found a solution that worked:

```
menu = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='grid__item one-half right-side']/ul/li[3]").click()
lo = driver.find_element(By.ID, "logout").click()
```